# Find point on a line at given distance from center of segment, perpendicular to this segment.

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations

I have 2D coordinate system. I have a segment *(p1; p2)* and distance *l* from center of this segment, where perpendicular to this segment theoretical line must have desired point.

---

https://i116.fastpic.org/big/2022/0129/29/0486465f0f8dcc455d66467fc7f07b29.png

---

I calculate midpoint of this segment: $$midpoint ( \frac{{p1.x+p2.x}}   {2}  ; \frac{{p1.y+p2.y}}  {2} )$$
I calculate factors *k* and *b* for a line through given segment:
$$ kSeg = \frac{p1.y - p2.y} {p1.x - p2.x} $$
$$ bSeg = p2.y - k * p2.x $$
I calculate factors k and b for perpendicular to segment line through midpoint:
$$ kNorm = \frac{-1} {kSeg} $$
$$ bNorm = midpoint.y() - kNorm * midpoint.x()$$

---

I Find 2 possible *x* from *midpoint* placed on given length.
Assume that:
$$ x_1 = midpoint.x$$
$$ y_1 = midpoint.y$$
$$ k = kNorm$$
$$ b = bNorm$$
$$ l = desired\quad segment\quad length\quad on\quad perpendicular\quad from\quad midpoint$$

Goal: find 2 possible points $(x_{21}, y_{21})$ and other $(x_{22}, y_{22})$

Solve equation system:
$$ \{ \matrix{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2 = l^2\\
y_2 = k*x2+b}$$

Open parentheses in the first equation:
$$x_2^2 - 2*x_1*x_2 + x_1^2    +    y_2^2 - 2*y_1*y_2 + y1^2    = l^2$$

Substitute *y2* with second equation:
$$ x_2^2 - 2*x_1*x_2 + x_1^2    +    (k*x_2+b)^2 - 2*y1*(k*x_2+b) + y1^2    = l^2$$

Open parentheses in the first equation and mark all terms with x2:
$$\color{red}{x_2^2} - \color{blue}{2*x_1*x_2} + x_1^2    +    \color{red}{k^2*x_2^2} + \color{blue}{2*k*b*x_2} + b^2  -  \color{blue}{2*k*y_1*x_2} + 2*y_1*b + y_1^2    = l^2$$

Transform to $A*x^2+B*x+C = 0$:
$$ (k^2 + 1)*x_2^2 + (-2*x_1 + 2*k*b - 2*k*y_1)*x + x_1^2+b^2+2*y_1*b+y_1^2-l^2 = 0 $$
$$ \begin{align}{ A = k^2 + 1 \\
B = -2*x_1 + 2*k*b - 2*k*y_1 \\
C = x_1^2+b^2+2*y_1*b+y_1^2-l^2}
\end{align} $$

Solving this equation gives 2 x: $x_{21}$ and $x_{22}$ 
The result must be 
$$ (x_{21}; k*x_{21}+b) $$
$$ (x_{22}; k*x_{22}+b) $$

---

Verifying
$$p1 = (146.0; 215.0)$$
$$p2 = (406.0; 212.0)$$
$$\begin{align}{kSeg = -0.011538461538461539\\
bSeg = 216.6846153846154}\end{align} $$
Line with segment equation:
$$y = -0.011538461538461539 * x + 216.6846153846154$$
$$midpoint = (276.0; 213.5)$$
$$\begin{align}{kNorm = 86.66666666666666\\
bNorm = -23706.499999999996}\end{align} $$
Perpendicular line through midpoint equation:
$$y = 86.66666666666666 * x - 23706.499999999996$$
Let desired x = 275.8, then desired y = 196,1667
$$desired\quad point(275.8; 196.1667) $$

How to get this x as root of quadratic equation?
I got: −582235982.137741417 = 0 :(
What I did wrong and how to do it right?

Comment: You did not specify $l$ so it is hard to check.

Comment: In verification $l$ can be calculated as length between $midpoint(276.0;213.5)$ and $desired\quad point(275.8;196.1667)$ and is about 17.33445381. $l^2 = 300.48328889$

Comment: The question says a 'given distance'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my error in substitution in equation system.
Correct is:

$$\begin{align}(x_2−x_1)^2+(y_2−y_1)^2=l^2\\
   y_2 = k * x_2 + b\\
   y_1 = k * x_1 + b\end{align}
$$

So:

$$\begin{align}
   (x_2-x_1)^2 + (k*x_2+b - k*x_1+b)^2 = l^2\\
    \\
   (x_2-x_1)^2 + ((k*x_2+b) - (k*x_1+b))^2 = l^2\\
    \\
   (x_2-x_1)^2 + (k*x_2+b - k*x_1-b)^2 = l^2\\
    \\
   (x_2-x_1)^2 + (k*x_2-k*x_1)^2 = l^2\\
    \\
   (x_2-x_1)^2 + (k*(x_2-x_1))^2 = l^2\\
     \\
   (x_2-x_1)^2 + k^2 * (x_2-x_1)^2 = l^2\\
     \\
   (x_2-x_1)^2 + k^2 * (x_2-x_1)^2 = l^2\\
    \\
   (x_2-x_1)^2 * (1 + k^2)^2 = l^2\\
    \\
   (x_2-x_1)^2 (1 + k^2)^2 - l^2 = 0 \quad | \quad / (1 + k^2)^2 \\
    \\
   (x2-x1)^2 - \frac{l^2} {(1 + k^2)^2} = 0\\
   \\
   x2^2 -2*x1*x2 + x1^2 - \frac{l^2} {(1 + k^2)^2} = 0\\
\end{align}
$$
Then:

$$
\begin{align}
 A = 1\\
 B = -2*x_1\\
 C = - \frac{l^2} {(1 + k^2)^2}
\end{align}
$$

Next solve quadratic equation with factors A, B, C:
$$A*x^2+B*x+C=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Compute the midpoint $m={1 \over 2} (p_1 + p_2)$.

Compute a direction perpendicular to the direction $p_2-p_1$, the easiest way is to rotate by $90^\circ$ anticlockwise, so the direction $(x,y)$ becomes $(-y,x)$. Call this direction $d$, note that $d \bot p_2-p_1$.

Scale the direction by dividing by the length $d^* = {1 \over \|d\|} d$.

Finally choose a point a distance $l$ away using the formula $m\pm l d^*$.